# jquery mobile accordion including canvas

Tags: jquery-mobile, canvas, width, accordion

I try to add several small canvas elements to accordion content area. How can I dynamically extend the width of the content?

http://jsfiddle.net/WBHUk/

```
<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" id="content01">
    </div><!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->


$('#content01').append('<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="d" id="acc01"></div>').trigger("create");
$('#acc01').append('<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" id="acc01a"><h3>First</h3><div id="acc01a1"></div></div>').trigger("create");
$('#acc01').append('<div data-role="collapsible" id="acc01b"><h3>Second</h3><p>TODO</p></div>').trigger("create");
$('#acc01').append('<div data-role="collapsible"><h3>Third</h3><p>TODO</p></div>').trigger("create");

for(var ch=0; ch<20; ch++){
    $('#acc01a1').append('<div id="c_panel'+ ch + '" class="chpanel"></div>');
    $('#c_panel' + ch).width(80);
    $('#c_panel' + ch).height(30);
    $('#c_panel' + ch).append('<canvas id="cccanvas' +ch+ '" class="cccanvas" width="80" height = "30"></canvas>').trigger("create");
    $('#c_panel' + ch).css( "position", "relative" );
    $('#c_panel' + ch).css( "float", "left" );
    $('#c_panel' + ch).css( "background-color", "yellow" );
    $('#c_panel' + ch).css( "margin", "2px" );
    $('#c_panel' + ch).css( "border-radius", "5px" );

    var ctx = $('#cccanvas' + ch)[0].getContext("2d");

}
```

Many thanks
Matt Jo

Comment: all collapsible contents or only the first one which contains canvas?

Comment: The idea is to add several canvas elements to every collapsible contents but as you can see the first one is already a problem.

Comment: sorry, I'd mean how to change the height like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7uaQ2/ but more dynamically

Comment: you need to override CSS style this way `.ui-collapsible-content { height: 130px !important; }` but this will affect all collapsible contents.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. Is it possible somehow to find out how much room all canvas elements need? In large screen there's need for less height than in narrow screen. Maybe it could be possible to find the y-value of the last canvas element?

Comment: This is what I'm trying to find out, you need to do it dynamically and might use @media queries for this for different screens. But for mobile phone I guess 350px is enough, when canvas(s) are formed into two columns and 10 rows. each canvas height is 30px + 4px margins, so 34 * 10 = 340px. You need to test it on larger screens to find out how much height colllapsible will need to show all canvas(s).